# iPhone TCP-IP byte order mapping?

Tags: c++, objective-c, visual-c++, tcp

Mac used the opposite byte order to Windows.  But is that still true for the iPhone?  Since I am doing TCP-IP(WiFi) from Windows to an iPhone, what does the byte conversion mapping look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network byte ordering (I mean IP, and therefore TCP too) is always big-endian: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Endianness_in_networking iPhone, like Windows, is little-endian: [iPhone platform: endianness (detection & swapping)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704721/iphone-platform-endianness-detection-swapping) You have to take byte-ordering into account only if you analyze TCP/IP packet headers; packet payload will arrive in the same byte ordering, as it was sent.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you care? on the network - use network byte order (typically Big Endian) and in the host, use host byte order i.e. use the appropriate conversion routines.

Answer (score 1):

The ARM architecture (at least as used in the iOS platform) is little-endian, just like x86.